# How to make a shape on a grid using at least two coordinate points, and make it so that I can recognize all space within the shape as "within bounds"?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I'm trying to make an algorithm in pseudocode that allows one to select points on a map(at least two(which would make a rectangle)), and then create a closed shape out of the points. After the shape is made, I need to be able to record the parts of the map within the shape so I can be able to tell if a point will be within the shape or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that the two points are **(x1,y1), (x2,y2)**

Since the shape you are creating is a rectangle, you only need two opposite points.

So let's assume **(x1,y1)** is the point that can be found on the top left and **(x2,y2)** is the point that can be found on the bottom right.

The bottom left point can be accessed by (x1,y2) [X stays the same because it's a rectangle, y is set to the y value of the bottom point, again, it's called the bottom left point, so the top-left point is being moved down.]

The top right point can be accessed by (x2,y1) [X stays the same again because it's again a rectangle, y is set to the y value of the top point because the bottom-right point is being moved up)

Visual Representation:

**(x1,y1) (?,?) 

(?,?) (x2,y2)**

So the points are now

**(x1,y1) (x2,y2) 

(x1,y2) (x2,y2)**

But sometimes, **(x2,y2)** can be switched with **(x1,y1)**, or they will be moved up or down, left or right. You will have to compare the coordinates to compare which points they correspond to.

Comment: Thanks! That makes pretty good sense.

Comment: How would I do it with more points?

Comment: Sorry forgot to do the checkmark thing